# How to print 1st string of file's line during second iteration in python

Tags: python-3.x

**Actually My file contents are.**
ttsighser66
dagadfgadgadgfadg
dafgad
fgadfgad
ttsighser63
sadfsadf
asfdas

**My code**

```
file=open("C:\\file.txt","r")
cont = []
for i in file:
  dd = i.strip("\n")
  cont.append(dd)
  cc = ",".join(cont)
  if "tt" in i:
     cc = ",".join(cont[:-1])
     print(cont[-1], cc)
     cont = []
```

**My code generate below Output:**

```
ttsighser66 
ttsighser63 dagadfgadgadgfadg,dafgad,fgadfgad
```

**But I want output like below format**

```
ttsighser66,dagadfgadgadgfadg,dafgad,fgadfgad  
ttsighser63,sadfsadf,asfdas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file=open("file.txt","r")
cont = []
for i in file:
    dd = i.strip("\n")
    cont.append(dd)
    #print('cc',cont)
    if "ttsighser" in i and len(cont) != 1:
        cc = ",".join(cont[:-1])
        print(cc)
        cont = []
        cont.append(dd)
print(",".join(cont))
```

Comment: You could have just the one `cont.append(dd)` line if you put it after the `if`. This would spare you the need to slice `cont` in the `join` call.

Comment: It worked according my my expectation. Thanks to all who shared their solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store any strings to a list and just need to print strings, you could try this instead.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    line_counter = 0
    file_lines = f.readlines()
    for i in file_lines:
        dd = i.strip()
        if "tt" in dd:
            print("{0}{1}".format("\n" if line_counter > 0 else "", dd), end="")
        else:
            print(",{0}".format(dd), end="")

    line_counter += 1

print("")
```

---

The reason why your code displays

```
ttsighser66 
ttsighser63 dagadfgadgadgfadg,dafgad,fgadfgad
```

instead of

```
ttsighser66,dagadfgadgadgfadg,dafgad,fgadfgad  
ttsighser63,sadfsadf,asfdas
```

is because when you first encounter `'ttsighser66'`, it is appended to `cont`. Then since `'ttsighser66'` contains `'tt'`, we would proceed to the conditional branch.

In the conditional branch, we would be joining the first and second to the last string in `cont` in `cc = ",".join(cont[:-1])`. However, since we only have `'ttsighser66'` in `cont`, `cont[:-1]` will give us `[]` (an empty list). Since `cont[:-1]` is empty, `",".join(cont[:-1])` will be empty as well. Thus, `cc` will be empty. Since `cc` is empty, `print(cont[-1], cc)` will give us `ttsighser66`.

In the second line, `ttsighser63 dagadfgadgadgfadg,dafgad,fgadfgad` gets displayed because `cont` contains more than one value already so it will also display the values before `'ttsighser63'`.

The remaining strings are not displayed because, based from your code, it would need another string containing `'tt'` before the strings in `cc` could be displayed.

Essentially, you require a pair of strings containing `'tt'` to display the strings between the pairs.

---

Additonal remark: The line `cc = ",".join(cont)` in your code seems pretty useless since its scope is limited to the `for` loop only and its value is being replaced inside the conditional branch.

Answer (score 0):

version 1 (all data in list of strings && 1 time print)

```
fp=open("file.txt", "r")
data = []
for line in fp:
    if "tt" in line:
        data.append(line.strip())
    else:
        data.append(data.pop() + "," + line.strip())
fp.close()
[print (data) for line in data]
```

Version 2 (all data in a single string && 1 time print)

```
fp=open("file.txt","r")
data = ""
for line in fp:
    if "tt" in line:
        data += "\n" + line.strip()
    else:
        data += ","+line.strip()
fp.close()
data = data[1:]
print (data)
```